# Faulty Url in FsLab package for F#

Tags: f#-data

I just downloaded this report called Analyzing and Visualizing Data with F# and am having a hard time just running the first example. This should probably be expected since the report is 7 years. I am running the first script which is as follows.

```
#load "packages/FsLab/FsLab.fsx"

open FSharp.Data


open XPlot.GoogleCharts

let wb = WorldBankData.GetDataContext()
wb.Countries
```

I get an error message that reads

Response from http://api.worldbank.org/country?per_page=1000&format=json&page=1:
{ "statusCode": 404, "message": "Resource not found" }

It looks like the url is broken because it seems that the worldbank has updated its api. When I use the url http://api.worldbank.org/v2/country in my browser it works. I noticed when I went to the source code that they have the base url hard coded in, so I was thinking I would just need to add "v2/" to it and it would work, but I am unfamiliar with how to load a edited library into my script.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your investigation is correct, even banks sometimes change their APIs :)

As for adding the library to your script, it depends on how your environment looks like, but basically you can fix the problem locally and/or globally.

For the local solution, once you compile your downloaded library with modified url, you can load or reference it as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/tutorials/fsharp-interactive/).

For the global solution, send a pull request that fixes the link in [this](https://github.com/fslaborg/zzarchive-OReilly.Report/blob/master/Chapter2.fsx) file, Tomáš Petřiček (the repo owner) is generally active and should merge it. And you will improve the world a little bit.